# Entry sharing lock fields based on another field

Tags: cognito-forms

I am needing to allow entry sharing but need to be able to lock fields based on another field.

I have hidden fields that using to say this selection is active.  I am able to Show WHEN the field is set to YES but still appears on the Entry page.

How can I lock or not display fields on the entry page if the hidden field is NO?

Answer (score 0):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  I believe you are asking if you can share an entry but have some fields editable and others not.  That behavior is not supported on Cognito Forms.